# クラス間で値を共有したい

Tags: flutter, dart

[A.dart]で定義した変数値（genreID）を[B.dart]の中で使いたいです。
どのように設定すればよいのでしょうか？
[A.dart]の一部の計算を[B.dart]に外だししており、画面遷移ではありません。
[image: 図の？？？の箇所になります。]

Answer (score 1):

下記momoさんの記事が詳しくわかりやすいです
https://medium.com/flutter-jp/state-1daa7fd66b94

公式ドキュメントも、結構わかりやすく解説してあるのでおすすめです^^
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

・InheritedWidget
・BLoC
・Provider + StateNotifer / ChangeNotifer

などがあります…
状態管理手法、多すぎです笑

個人的な見解としては、画面内で済む処理は、setState or RiverPodで行う
画面をまたぐ状態に関しては、StateNotifer + Provider + freezed　が今のところは良いかなと思います
flutterはまだまだ、破壊的変更が多いので、これを使っとけば間違いないと言えません
Providerは公式推奨で、ある程度わかりやすいのでおすすめですね

コードの例はこちら：https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple